# Usando retorno de um método AngularJS em outro controllerJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Tenho este método em meu script controllerJS e precisaria usar o response desse método em outro controllerJs.

Como faço ?

```
app.controller("loginController", function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.usuarios = {};

        $scope.autenticar = function() {    

                $http.post("/usuarioLogadoPermissoes", $scope.usuarios).then(
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.usuarios = response.data;
                            var jsonAux = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                            localStorage.setItem("usuarioLogado",jsonAux);                                  
                        },
                        function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });

            };  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um serviço para te auxiliar nesta tarefa, assim o código ainda fica mais reutilizável.

Segue um exemplo (pode conter erros, fiz correndo).

https://gist.github.com/eabreusantos/cdd1b24acc9c0e3547a36368a17b29b6

Pra te ajudar a melhorar e legibilidade do cógido, usa o Style Guide do John Papa:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md